# Equivalence between removable singularity criteria

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, solution-verification, laurent-series, singularity

I have observed, from my complex analysis course and Wikipedia respectively, that a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, \, z \mapsto f(z)$ having a removable singularity at $z_0$ is equivalent to the following statements :

\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)(z-z_0) = 0 
\end{equation}

where the first comes from the Laurent series for which $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and, more specifically here, $a_n = 0$ when $n < 0$. I want to prove the equivalence between these two criteria but I'm not sure how to end the proof and if it's valid. Let's begin with the implication:

\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)(z-z_0) &= \lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n\right)(z-z_0)\right)\\
&= \lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{z\to z_0} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cdot 0\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Now the reciprocal :

\begin{align}
0&=\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)(z-z_0)\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n\right)(z-z_0)\right)\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1} + \lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1}
\end{align}
We have seen in the above development that this last term is $0$. Therefore we have
\begin{align}
0&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+1}
\end{align}
But I fail to see how that implies $a_n = 0 \quad \forall n < 0$, is it just a matter of showing that $\forall n <0$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^{n+1} = \pm \infty
\end{equation}
and therefore the $a_n$s should compensate by being equal to zero ?

Comment: This should help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem

Comment: Yes it's a nice proof too, but is it possible to finish mine the way I started it ?

Comment: Hmm I don't really see a way to finish your proof, I'm afraid. Not to say it's impossible though.